# Comparing individual elements of two lists of the same length in DrRacket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function that takes two lists (must be of equal length) and then goes through each list comparing individual items.

For example: `(1 2 3)` and `(2 4 5)` would return true because each element of list 2 is greater than the corresponding element in list 1.  `(1 2 3)` and `(0 4 1)` would return `false` as would `(1 2 3)` and `(1 2 3 4)` since they are of different size.  Using Dr Racket

```
(define (each-bigger? a-lon another-lon)
  (cond
    (if
    [(= (length a-lon) (length another-lon))true]
    (then
    [(> (first a-lon) (first another-lon))true]
    (then
    [(> (rest a-lon) (rest another-lon))true]
    [else false])))))
```

this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you've got both your syntax and your logic wrong. I believe your intention was to write something like this:

```scm
(define (each-bigger? lst1 lst2)
  (cond
    ((and (null? lst1)  (null? lst2)) #t) ; both lists are empty => true
    ((or  (null? lst1)  (null? lst2)) #f) ; only one is empty => not the same length => false
    ((>=  (car lst1)    (car lst2))   #f) ; first element of lst1 >= first element of lst2 => false
    (else (each-bigger? (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))) ; recur on the rest of the list
```

which can be shortened to

```scm
(define (each-bigger? lst1 lst2)
  (or (and (null? lst1) (null? lst2))               ; EITHER both lists are empty
      (and (not (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2)))     ; OR  1) none of them is empty
           (< (car lst1) (car lst2))                ;     2) AND first element of lst1 < first element of lst2
           (each-bigger? (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))  ;     3) AND each-bigger? is true for the rest of both lists
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you want to implement a solution from scratch, and @uselpa's advice is spot-on. But in a non-academic context you should use existing procedures for solving this kind of problem, in particular [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29) is your best friend here:

```
(define (each-bigger? lst1 lst2)
  (and (= (length lst1) (length lst2))
       (andmap < lst1 lst2)))
```

The trick is that `andmap` applies a predicate on elements of both lists, passing as parameters the first element of `lst1` and the first element of `lst2`, then the second element of `lst1` and the second element of `lst2`, and so on (BTW, `andmap` accepts *one or more* lists as parameters, as long as the predicate receives the same number of parameters).

If all the applications of the predicate return `#t` then `#t` is returned, if a single predicate returns `#f` then evaluation stops and `#f` is returned. In the above example, the predicate is just `<`, applied pair-wise between the two lists. It works as expected:

```
(each-bigger? '(1 2 3) '(2 4 5))
=> #t
(each-bigger? '(1 2 3) '(0 4 1))
=> #f
(each-bigger? '(1 2 3) '(2 4 5 6))
=> #f
```

Comment: Unfortunately `andmap` does not handle the situation where the lists do not have the same size.

Comment: @uselpa that's all right for this question, as stated: "write a function that takes two lists _(must be of equal length)_ ..."

Comment: It also says "would return false as would (1 2 3) and (1 2 3 4) since they are of different size".

Comment: @uselpa mmm, I missed that part. Right, I'm updating my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment? any suggestion to improve my answer, or what's wrong with it in its current state?